# Node server not handling async post requests from client properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

We have a node server which doesn't handle post requests properly when they are made asynchronously. When the requests are made synchronously, it handles them fine.

There is a node api server and to mimic a client, there is  node script which makes a post request to the server.

While making a single post request or post requests in a loop synchronously, everything works as expected.

While making asynchronous post requests in a loop to the server, the code doesn't execute properly.

Here is the code on the server side. This method is called from router.post() method.

```
async insert(params) {
  let account = new Account();
  try {
    let totalLicenses = await this.getLicenses(params);

    if (totalLicenses === 0) throw new AccountError('NO_AVAILABLE_LICENSE');

    let accountResponse = await account.insert(params);
    let useLicense = await license.use(accountResponse, params);

    /*
      Do other account setup stuff here
    */

    return accountResponse;
  } catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

`getLicenses(params)` is a async function that prepares the sql query and awaits the response from a queryDb method which wraps the callback in a promise. Here is the code:

```
getLicense(params) {
  let vals = [...arguments],
      sql = 'my sql query';

  try {
    return await queryDb(sql, val);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error()
  }
}
```

We are using mysql package to talk to db. This is what queryDb method looks like.

```
queryDb(query, vals) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, vals, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) reject(err);

      resolve(results);
    }
  }
}
```

While making asynchronous post requests in a loop to the server, the insert method above executes `this.getLicenses(params)` method for the requests and then calls the `account.insert(params)` for the requests and then `license.use(accountResponse, params)` for the requests.

This becomes a problem when let's say a client has 3 licenses available and they send 5 asynchronous post requests. Technically, it should throw error for the last 2 requests but that is not the case. What ends up happening is, it inserts all 5 accounts since it calls `this.getLicenses(params)` for all 5 requests before proceeding to insert the account.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if your requests are being made asynchronously, then the definition of the "last" 2 requests inevitably becomes ambiguous, at best. Also you say "that's not the case" but then fail to say what _is_ the case.

Comment: @ADyson Oh sorry, just edited my post to make more clear. hope that explains.

Comment: maybe it would be better if the test for the number of licences and insert of new record was done in one stored procedure, which wraps all the necessary queries in a transaction? Then the test for the number of licences would be more reliable I think, since the test and insert are all within one atomic operation. I suspect at the moment there's a problem because the getLicenses code can run and return "true", then in the meantime an insert from another request can run, and then the insert from the earlier request. And there's no real guarantee over the ordering of the operations.

Comment: hmm, i don't think that solves it since when currently it checks for available licenses for all requests and then proceeds to insert account for all of the requests and then use the license of all the request.

Is there a way i can guarantee of it on server side?

Comment: I'm not sure how what you've described proves that a transactional approach wouldn't work? In that scenario you'd only have 1 DB call per request to both check, and insert. But it would only insert if a license was available when the SQL runs, and since it's in a transaction, it guarantees that any previous inserts have already run and can be read, before the next check is made. At the moment, you can't guarantee in which order your queries will be made. With my code, for your scenario at least 2 requests should fail on the basis of the license count, although _which_ 2 cannot be guaranteed...

Comment: ...because the requests themselves are async. All it guarantees is that the database queries cannot cross over each other and report an incorrect license count.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. I'll try that approach. Thanks! :)

Comment: You will need to show us the code of `getLicenses`, according to your description it should be responsible for only handing out 3 instead of 5 licenses. Where's that counter implemented?

Comment: Modified my post to include `getLicenses`.

Comment: @ADyson Stored Procedures did it! Thanks for the help!